# Stacked Bar Chart summing repeated daily likes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, time-series

I have table with two columns, `Date` and `Likes`. For each row in `Date`, I have a value in `Likes`, this pair represents the the likes we received every day.

I want to create stacked bar chart, grouped by the days, so we can see the components of the summed days. When I tried to achieve this, I got a simple bar chart, without the components.

Any ideas?

[My sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4VHb.png)

Answer (score 1):

If the sort of chart you would like is as shown, then a change in layout might be advisable:

[image: WA10944 example]